# Cesium - Camera in Columbus view

Tags: camera, cesiumjs

I was using the below function to fly the camera to required camera view in 3D view till now. But when I try this same function in Columbus view, the camera view is not as required.

```
           goToLocation(-114.07201, 51.04357, 198.21, 43.20, 68.65, 1);

           function goToLocation(longitude, latitude, altitude, heading, tilt, duration) {
                var coords = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(longitude, latitude, altitude, Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84);
                var heading = Cesium.Math.toRadians(heading);
                var tilt = Cesium.Math.toRadians(tilt - 90);
                var camera_v = viewer.camera;
                var options = {
                    destination: coords,
                    duration: duration,
                    orientation: {
                        heading: heading,
                        pitch: tilt,
                        roll: 0.0
                    }
                };
                camera_v.flyTo(options);
            }
```

Can anyone please suggest any changes to be done to this function for columbus view?

Comment: Hmm, this seems to work OK [in my test here](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Hello%20World.html&label=Showcases&gist=f5c12037194eaf95070ad63960ac94c2) even if I switch to Columbus View.  But yesterday I was having trouble with flyTo in CV.  Can you reproduce this in Cesium 1.30?

Comment: yes. I am using Cesium 1.30. It works well in your example but not in my page. Do you have any idea about why it does not work?

Comment: I got rid of "var" in front of `heading` and `tilt` in my example, since jsHint was telling me it was re-defining the function parameters.  I don't think too much else changed.  Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: No console errors...

Comment: Very odd.  Can you get this to fail in [Sandcastle](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html), and share that?  Seems like the failure may be triggered by or enabled by some other aspect of your app that you haven't reproduced here.